# Mongoose/MongoDB not saving objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

In my last commit, I have my POST route working perfectly, but after starting implementing PassportJS I'm not able to save new users anymore. I have been deleting the db and the collections in a couple of occasions mainly because I've been changing the structure of the schema, so I want to ask if any kind of corruption is possible, knowing that I always have been manipulating Mongo through MongoDB Compass.

```
//DB setup
    mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', true);
    this.connection = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGODB_URL || MONGO_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
    });
    this.connection.once('open', args => console.log('DB is connected'));
    this.connection.once('error', err => console.log(err));
```

This is the method executed by the route and the route itself.

```
private async postUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const {username, password, email} = req.body;
    console.log(username + " " + password + " " + email);
    const {salt, hash} = this.genPass(password);
    console.log(salt + " " + hash);
    const newUser = new User({ username: username, password: hash, salt: salt, email: email });
    console.log(newUser);
    await newUser.save((err, newUser) => {
        console.log('smth');
        if (err) {
            res.json('username or email already exist');
            return console.error(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(newUser.get('username') + ' created');
            res.json({data: newUser});
        }
    });
}

this.router.post('/sign', (req: Request, res:Response) => {
        this.postUser(req, res)
            .then(x => console.log (x));
    });
```

The schema

```
const userSchema = new Schema ({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: { type: String, required: true},
    salt: {type: String, required: true},
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique:true, lowercase: true}
},
{
  timestamps: true,
});

export default model('user', userSchema);
```

Console output

```
(node:19004) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and 
will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover
and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

Server on port 3000
DB is connected
admin passw email
cf0bcf9bd942010fba7bfd1bcde96ae93b2e1a55f078a70b1cb48f000551c4e1 
e73a50fb837a55abd9bcc5da1e635cb0c825663aaaf2b3318f8f9bc38ea89e50af2c70f4ee247256a282709b9a6abee0d9ba5
a574d6dec19d519692683027135
{
  _id: 5ef6b7111668ca4a3c0e8332,
  username: 'admin',
  password: 
  'e73a50fb837a55abd9bcc5da1e635cb0c825663aaaf2b3318f8f9bc38ea89e50af2c
   70f4ee247256a282709b9a6abee0d9ba5a574d6dec19d519692683027135',
  salt: 'cf0bcf9bd942010fba7bfd1bcde96ae93b2e1a55f078a70b1cb48f000551c4e1',
  email: 'email'
 }
 undefined
 POST /sign - - ms - -
```

(Also would like to ask about that deprecation warning but I don't think it's related to the main topic of this post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Instead of using *createConnection()* I used *mongoose.connect()* and when I needed the object *Connection* I used *mongoose.connection*. Weird af I think and I would love to know the reason but if it works it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you user is saved to the database, `save` won't return the inserted document

```
await newUser.save((err) => {
        if (err) { 
     ///.... 
    }
```

also you have to check if the user exist in the database before hand

```
User.find({ email: email, (err, user) =>{
     if (err) throw err 
      if(user) return console.log("user already exist")
       //... your code 
    const newUser = new User({ username: username, password: hash, salt: salt, // construct a document
     email: email });
     
     newUser.save()
      
});
```

to make mongoose deprecated errors disappear add this lines

```
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true)
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true)
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)
```

Comment: The syntax I'm using there was working before implementing the crypto stuff, and I'm constantly checking the database so I'm sure is not holding any data. The check and every error management are intended to happen in the callback, so if it was the case of duplicated data I would be getting a console output as I was doing before.